# Why am I seeing Modernizr JavaScript errors on page load?

Tags: javascript, 9

When I load pages on our live site (D9), we see these Modernizr errors from contextual links JS, and the contextual links don't appear on the site.

[image: Chrome JS Console output]

However, Modernizr does appear to be loaded ahead of the contextual links JS, as you can see from the two further screen captures, so I don't see why RegionView and VisualView should think it is undefined.

[image: Modernizr load time]
[image: Region View load time]

and also the Modernizr object is available in the JS console after page load

[image: Modernizr object in console]

I have no idea how to progress solving this. To make things worse, this doesn't seem to happen on our test sites, which are running on the same codebase.

Comment: Are the scripts loaded async? If so the order you’re seeing might be request start, not request end

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Clive. I don't believe they are loaded async from looking at the HTML, plus my understanding (which might be wrong, I am no expert in this) is that the Timing panel in the screen grabs shows that modernizr request was completed before the RegionView request started?

Comment: It says *Started at 1.73 s* and *Started at 3.16 s*, which means that RegionView.js was received after receiving modernizr.js. It seems they are asynchronous calls since they are queued at 1.63 s and 1.68 s.

Comment: Thank you Apaderno, does that mean modernizr would have been loaded by the time RegionView attempted to reference it, or might there be other reasons why it wasn't?

Comment: That depends from what the code does after asynchronously loading the files. If it waits for the files to be loaded, it should not say that `Modernizr` isn't defined.

Comment: I cannot see any 'waiting' happening but I do not really understand how all this stuff works. As far as I can see the RegionView code just assumes the Modernizr object is available, there is no checking that it is loaded. Is there some way I can force a dependency, maybe through YML files?